# If $L$ is context-free, then $L$ is regular

Tags: regular-language, context-free-grammar

Let $L \subset \{a\}^*$ and assume that $L$ is context-free. Prove that $L$ is regular.
Please hint me.

Comment: This is a consequence of [Parikh's_theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parikh's_theorem).